# The remote host forcibly closed an existing connection

Tags: java

I use redis to keep my sessions,when my project start,this occurs:
almost a loop in 1 minute.

This project based on SpringBoot2.0.1 and redis vsersion is 4.0 on docker.

```
===2019-07-12 11:11:02.468 INFO  io.lettuce.core.protocol.ConnectionWatchdog Line:106 - Reconnecting, last destination was /10.131.9.17:39404
===2019-07-12 11:11:02.630 INFO  io.lettuce.core.protocol.ReconnectionHandler Line:106 - Reconnected to 10.131.9.17:39404
===2019-07-12 11:12:05.366 INFO  io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler Line:116 - null Unexpected exception during request: java.io.IOException: The remote host forcibly closed an existing connection
java.io.IOException: The remote host forcibly closed an existing connection
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1108)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It seems that redis server shutdown the connections,and then my program reconnected to it again.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is redis setting error. set timeou = 0 can be fixed it.

## Close the connection after a client is idle for N seconds (0 to disable)

timeout 0